# Subtracting one text string from another leaving unique characters, perhaps using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

Is there any way to subtract one column of data containing text from another column containing text and get third column containing unique charcters, for example using awk eg.

Input

```
ab   a
cd   d    
efg  ef
```

desired output:

```
ab   a   b
cd   d   c
efg  ef  g
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, `awk` is a suitable choice:

```
awk 'NF{t=$1;gsub("["$2"]","",t);print$0,t}' input
```

In case the second field may contain characters with special meaning in regular expression character classes, those have to be escaped. Solving that in POSIX `awk` is lengthy, so I post the GNU `awk` alternative only:

```
gawk 'NF{print$0,gensub("["gensub(/([\[\]^-])/,"\\\\\\1","g",$2)"]","","g",$1)}' input
```

Comment: Great that works well, however for me it takes into account position in first column so that there is an output only if character differs at first position (left hand position) in column 1.....am I doing something wrong??

Comment: Ah yes my mistake.............works now!!! Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 1):

Manatworks solution is of course fine. This is just a pure bash alternative.

```
while read line
do
  in=${line/ */}
  pat=${line/* /}
  echo $line ${in/$pat}
done < aba.dat

ab a b
cd d c
efg ef g
```

- In `in` replace (`/`) from $line what is a blank, followed by something - not in regex, but globbing style.
- In `pat` it is the opposite: remove what is before the blank. Removing, because the replacement part of ${src/pattern/replacement} is blank.
- ${in/$pat} replaces `pat` in `in` with nothing. The pat var needs to be marked as variable `$` in contrast to the first variable/part (in).

Comment: If you don't care about preserving the amount of whitespace between the existing columns: `while read -r in pat; do echo "$in $pat ${in/$pat}"; done`